# array index is not integer on map

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have written the following code:

```
#include "joinCommand.h"

joinCommand::joinCommand(map<string, Task *>* threadMap) {
this->threadMap=threadMap;
}

string joinCommand::execute(vector<string> args) {   
   if(threadMap->count(&args.at(1)) ==1){
    Task* t= this->threadMap["fkjk"];
 }
}
```

The compiler gives an error message for the following line:

```
Task* t= this->threadMap["fkjk"];
```

The error message is:

> array index is not integer.

How am I supposed to get the value of `Task*` from the map?

Comment: You need to post a proper [mcve]. I'm guessing you want `(*this->threadMap)["fkjk"]`

Comment: Since `this->threadMap` is a pointer you need to dereference it `(*(this->threadMap))["fkjk"]`

Comment: thanks man ! it works now

Comment: You should not need to use `this->` in your `joinCommand::execute()` method (compare with the first line of the method). Use a name differing from the attribute name for the constructor parameter, so you don’t need to use `this->` there, too.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is a little subtle... `threadMap` is accessible by `this->threadMap`, but it's also a pointer. The type of `this->threadMap` is `map<string, Task *> *` *not* `map<string, Task *>`, so when you do the `[]` operator on it, it's acting on the pointer and not on the dereferenced object.

You would need to do this:

```
Task* t= (*this->threadMap)["fkjk"];
```

More explicitly:

```
Task* t= (*(this->threadMap))["fkjk"];
```

Alternatively you can directly call the brackets operator with the arrow syntax:

```
Task* t= this->threadMap->operator[]("fkjk");
```

As another alternative, you can use stl map's named methods instead of overloaded operators:

```
Task* t= this->threadMap->at("fkjk");
```

Read the documentation here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

This all being said and done, I suggest you use STL map's find() method to return an iterator, and check it for validity then dereference that instead, something like this:

```
map<string, Task*>::iterator it = this->threadMap->find(&args.at(1));
if (it != this->threadMap->end()) {
   Task *t = *it; // or just directly use *it or it->
   // continue to use the valid 't' pointer
}
```

Comment: (1) cplusplus is considered a sub-par reference. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) would be a better link. (2) I don't usually upvote typo answers, but you explained the subtlety nicely. So here's one from me.

Answer (score 0):

From the first function I guess `this->threadMap` is a pointer because you assign another pointer to it. This guess well complies with the error message.

So the solution is to dereference the pointer before using functions from `std::map`:

```
(*this->threadMap)["fkjk"];
```